# How to find a frequent character in a string written in pseudocode. Thanks

Tags: pseudocode

Most Frequent Character 
Design a program that prompts the user to enter a string, and displays the character that appears most frequently in the string.

It is a homework question, but my teacher wasn't helpful and its driving me crazy i can't figure this out.

Thank You in advance.

This is what i have so far!

```
Declare String str
Declare Integer maxChar
Declare Integer index

Set maxChar = 0

Display “Enter anything you want.”
Input str

For index = 0 To length(str) – 1
    If str[index] =
```

And now im stuck. I dont think its right and i dont know where to go with it!

Comment: Well, this is a homework question, so it's not OK for us to just give you the solution. How would you go about it? Do you have any thoughts at all?

Comment: I know i need to have the string go through a loop to go through every character.  I know there isnt a function for getting the maximum/frequent character in a string. I just dont know how to put it together. How many variables? how many arrays? if i need more than one loop and how to set that loop up. I am not here trying to cheat or anything...its just bugging me that i cant figure it out.  I would appreciate any help. I am better at learning at examples or seeing how the answer looks so i can understand how it works. The book im using doesnt have an example i need.

Comment: You're correct, you have to loop through every character. Then, you have to use a data structure that would let you save pairs like this: ("character", "number of times it was seen"). Do you know a data structure that could do the job?

Comment: This is what i have for now!

Declare String str
Declare Integer maxChar
Declare Integer index

Set maxChar = 0

Display “Enter anything you want.”
Input str

For index = 0 To length(str) – 1
 If str[index] =


And now im stuck...i just dont think it looks right...i dont know what to do

Comment: Try editing the question and putting that in there instead of the comment please.

Comment: Done...and thanks for hleping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the way you want to do it is:
"Go through every character in the string and remember the character we've seen most times".

However, that won't work. If we only remember the count for a single character, like "the character we've seen most times is 'a' with 5 occurrences", we can't know if perhaps the character in the 2nd place doesn't jump ahead.

So, what you have to do is this:

1. Go through every character of the string.
2. For every character, increase the occurrence count for that character. Yes, you have to save this count for every single character you encounter. Simple variables like `string` or `int` are not going to be enough here.
3. When you're done, you're left with a bunch of data looking like "a"=5, "b"=2, "e"=7,... you have to go though that and find the highest number (I'm sure you can find examples for finding the highest number in a sequence), then return the letter which this corresponds to.

Not a complete answer, I know, but that's all I'm going to say.

If you're stuck, I suggest getting a pen and a piece of paper and trying to calculate it manually. Try to think - how would you do it without a computer? If your answer is "look and see", what if the text is 10 pages? I know it can be pretty confusing, but the point of all this is to get you used to a different way of thinking. If you figure this one out, the next time will be easier because the basic principles are always the same.

Comment: Thank you..i appreciate your help. I hope i can get this.  I understand what needs to be done..im just confused on how to get it done.

Comment: mind taking a look at what i have for now? and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I have created to count all occurences in a string.

```
String abc = "aabcabccc";
char[] x = abc.toCharArray();
String _array = "";
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) //copy distinct data to a new string
{
    if(_array.indexOf(x[i]) == -1)
    _array = _array+x[i];
}
char[] y = _array.toCharArray();
int[] count1 = new int[_array.length()];
for(int j = 0; j<x.length;j++) //count occurences
{
    count1[new String(String.valueOf(y)).indexOf(x[j])]++;
}
for(int i = 0; i<y.length;i++) //display
{
    System.out.println(y[i] + " = " + count1[i]);
}
```